# How would you go about figuring out who should be scheduled where?

Tags: planning

If we had a cohort of staff who worked in downtown Toronto and you had to schedule some of them for meetings in Pickering, Oakville, and Vaughan. How would you go about figuring out who should be scheduled where?

Comment: You schedule them according to need, and according to their employment contract.

Comment: Some locations might be more convenient than others for an employee. I would ask the people what their preferred location is and let them decide what meeting to attend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obviously you have to do it according to their first names.

So, everyone that has a first name starting with P should go to Pickering. Examples are Peter, Pauline, and Pedro.

People whose name starts with O should be scheduled in Oakville. So those would be those like Oscar, Owen, and Oliver etc.

People whose name starts with V should be scheduled in Vaughan. So, Victor, Victoria, and Vanessa should be sent to Vaughan. If you have an employee actually named Vaughan, then they obviously should run the meeting.

There may be a few people whose name does not start with P, O, or V. For these people you should schedule meetings in the nearest city that starts with that letter.

People named Xaviar and Zach get the day off.

Comment: That was ... funny.